# Multiple captions for an image - click on links to see one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

What I'm trying to do is something like you see at http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMimc1109704.  (Click Play and go to page 5 - the interactive physical exam.)  I think they are doing this with Flash, but I'd like to use javascript/jQuery.

Basically there's an image that has multiple captions.  The captions have arrows that point to different parts of the image, but that's not essential for me.  When you click on different links, different captions appear.

Would I tackle this as an image map?  I.e. create a map, and use jQuery to toggle different parts of the map?  Is there a plug-in that does that?  Google searches aren't helping me - but maybe I don't know what to look for.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem and I found imageMapster. Check out
http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html#beatles
I think this is what you want to do. Just this solution today, haven't figured it out yet. Looks promising though. Otherwise check out qTip2 
http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/
Maybe some adaptions let you/us do what we wanna do
Good luck! Keep u updated if I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need jQuery?

Anyway, put your main image down, and set its position to be fixed where you want it. You could even put it in a nice container div, just make sure all your caption divs are relative to the same parent. Then put fixed position divs of your caption images over it with a higher z-index in your css. Then place your caption images at the appropriate top and left positions until they are correct. Of course, use transparent PNGs.

All you need to do to toggle them is set the element's style.display to "none" or "inherit"